# How to implement different colors in the same line using vscode.TreeDataProvider

Tags: vscode-extensions

I'm implementing a View in VSCode which will display files and their line and columns.
Checking the examples provided by Microsoft, none of them seem to be similar to what I'm trying to achieve.

In the "Problems" view in VSCode there's the same of what I'm trying to build.
The line information is normal/black, while the Line and other information should stay greyed out (or any other color).

Does anyone has an small example snippet for this?

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pz6Zq.png)

Thanks in advance.

-Daniel

The **nodeDependecy** example from the link below shows the Dependency Version for each module as greyed out (different color from the line).

https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/tree-view

Answer (score 0):

This has been asked before, but I cannot find a question at SO (the search function is just terrible). There's no way you can format tree items in a tree provider, because the API is only available internally (e.g. for the file tree).

Instead you could create a webview and show your own treeview there.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I'm using the examples provided by Microsoft implementing `TreeDataProvider` class. Then, on the `TreeItem`, for each line I can add an icon and make it similar to "Problems" view.

This is the code to define the icon in the `TreeItem` implementation. 

this.iconPath === this.children ? this.iconPath = new vscode.ThemeIcon('arrow-circle-up', new vscode.ThemeColor('charts.red')) : undefined

Comment: Icons yes, colors/formatting no.